# Getting StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location. Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm building a Java Android Project using Firebase and its Firestore. The problem is in my AddPostFragment:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class EditProfilePage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    String storagepath = "Users_Profile_Cover_image/";
    String uid;
    ImageView set;
    TextView profilepic, editname, editpassword;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 100;
    private static final int STORAGE_REQUEST = 200;
    private static final int IMAGEPICK_GALLERY_REQUEST = 300;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICKCAMERA_REQUEST = 400;
    String cameraPermission[];
    String storagePermission[];
    Uri imageuri;
    String profileOrCoverPhoto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile_page);

        profilepic = findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
        editname = findViewById(R.id.editname);
        set = findViewById(R.id.setting_profile_image);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        editpassword = findViewById(R.id.changepassword);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");
        cameraPermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        storagePermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(firebaseUser.getEmail());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String image = "" + dataSnapshot1.child("image").getValue();

                    try {
                        Glide.with(EditProfilePage.this).load(image).into(set);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        editpassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pd.setMessage("Changing Password");
                showPasswordChangeDailog();
            }
        });

        profilepic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pd.setMessage("Updating Profile Picture");
                profileOrCoverPhoto = "image";
                showImagePicDialog();
            }
        });

        editname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pd.setMessage("Updating Name");
                showNamephoneupdate("name");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(firebaseUser.getEmail());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String image = "" + dataSnapshot1.child("image").getValue();

                    try {
                        Glide.with(EditProfilePage.this).load(image).into(set);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        editpassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pd.setMessage("Changing Password");
                showPasswordChangeDailog();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(firebaseUser.getEmail());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String image = "" + dataSnapshot1.child("image").getValue();

                    try {
                        Glide.with(EditProfilePage.this).load(image).into(set);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        editpassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pd.setMessage("Changing Password");
                showPasswordChangeDailog();
            }
        });
    }

    // checking storage permission ,if given then we can add something in our storage
    private Boolean checkStoragePermission() {
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result;
    }

    // requesting for storage permission
    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        requestPermissions(storagePermission, STORAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    // checking camera permission ,if given then we can click image using our camera
    private Boolean checkCameraPermission() {
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        boolean result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result && result1;
    }

    // requesting for camera permission if not given
    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        requestPermissions(cameraPermission, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }

    // We will show an alert box where we will write our old and new password
    private void showPasswordChangeDailog() {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_update_password, null);
        final EditText oldpass = view.findViewById(R.id.oldpasslog);
        final EditText newpass = view.findViewById(R.id.newpasslog);
        Button editpass = view.findViewById(R.id.updatepass);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(view);
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        editpass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String oldp = oldpass.getText().toString().trim();
                String newp = newpass.getText().toString().trim();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(oldp)) {
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfilePage.this, "Current Password cant be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newp)) {
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfilePage.this, "New Password cant be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
                updatePassword(oldp, newp);
            }
        });
    }

    // Now we will check that if old password was authenticated
    // correctly then we will update the new password
    private void updatePassword(String oldp, final String newp) {
        pd.show();
        final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        AuthCredential authCredential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(user.getEmail(), oldp);
        user.reauthenticate(authCredential)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        user.updatePassword(newp)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        pd.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(EditProfilePage.this, "Changed Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        pd.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(EditProfilePage.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfilePage.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    // Updating name
    private void showNamephoneupdate(final String key) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Update" + key);

        // creating a layout to write the new name
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setHint("Enter" + key);
        layout.addView(editText);
        builder.setView(layout);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                final String value = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
                    pd.show();

                    // Here we are updating the new name
                    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                    result.put(key, value);
                    databaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).updateChildren(result).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            pd.dismiss();

                            // after updated we will show updated
                            Toast.makeText(EditProfilePage.this, " updated ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(EditProfilePage.this, "Unable to update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    if (key.equals("name")) {
                        final DatabaseReference databaser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
                        Query query = databaser.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid);
                        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    String child = databaser.getKey();
                                    dataSnapshot1.getRef().child("uname").setValue(value);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfilePage.this, "Unable to update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }

    // Here we are showing image pic dialog where we will select
    // and image either from camera or gallery
    private void showImagePicDialog() {
        String options[] = {"Camera", "Gallery"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Pick Image From");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // if access is not given then we will request for permission
                if (which == 0) {
                    if (!checkCameraPermission()) {
                        requestCameraPermission();
                    } else {
                        pickFromCamera();
                    }
                } else if (which == 1) {
                    if (!checkStoragePermission()) {
                        requestStoragePermission();
                    } else {
                        pickFromGallery();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == IMAGEPICK_GALLERY_REQUEST) {
                imageuri = data.getData();
                uploadProfileCoverPhoto(imageuri);
            }
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICKCAMERA_REQUEST) {
                uploadProfileCoverPhoto(imageuri);
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean camera_accepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean writeStorageaccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (camera_accepted && writeStorageaccepted) {
                        pickFromCamera();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enable Camera and Storage Permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
            case STORAGE_REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean writeStorageaccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (writeStorageaccepted) {
                        pickFromGallery();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enable Storage Permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    // Here we will click a photo and then go to startactivityforresult for updating data
    private void pickFromCamera() {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Temp_pic");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Temp Description");
        imageuri = this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
        Intent camerIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        camerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageuri);
        startActivityForResult(camerIntent, IMAGE_PICKCAMERA_REQUEST);
    }

    // We will select an image from gallery
    private void pickFromGallery() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, IMAGEPICK_GALLERY_REQUEST);
    }

    // We will upload the image from here.
    private void uploadProfileCoverPhoto(final Uri uri) {
        pd.show();

        // We are taking the filepath as storagepath + firebaseauth.getUid()+".png"
        String filepathname = storagepath + "" + profileOrCoverPhoto + "_" + firebaseUser.getUid();
        StorageReference storageReference1 = storageReference.child(filepathname);
        storageReference1.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!uriTask.isSuccessful()) ;

                // We will get the url of our image using uritask
                final Uri downloadUri = uriTask.getResult();
                if (uriTask.isSuccessful()) {

                    // updating our image url into the realtime database
                    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put(profileOrCoverPhoto, downloadUri.toString());
                    databaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).updateChildren(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(EditProfilePage.this, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(EditProfilePage.this, "Error Updating ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfilePage.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                pd.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(EditProfilePage.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I can choose a pic from my gallery or take a pic, but when I upload it always fails. The logcat has this exception: StorageException has occurred.Object does not exist at location.Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404

I'm currently building the project on my physical device. I have made my database public, and grant permission on my physical phone.
I'm mimicing a pretty old code so it can have some problem with the depracated functions, I really dont know what is the problem here. In the old project it worked fine. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As you've provided a fair chunk of code here, please reduce it to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will help others be able to focus on the problem at hand rather than sift through many lines of code.

Comment: On a first pass, I can see that you have many calls to `query.addValueEventListener` where you attach a listener but never detach those same listeners. Over time you will have many listeners firing at the same time that will conflict with each other. I also see that there are many places where you are attaching listeners from inside other listeners. This will have the same effect of causing unexpected behaviour. Consider reviewing the [Chaining tasks documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#chaining). Once you've made those changes, please update your question.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500** (five hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).